# How to get the length of an array in a state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app with an API call. I'm setting a state with an initial array and set it to a JSON array in API call. I need to get the array length for a calculation. I tried the following code but didn't work! Console only says "**Undefined**"

```
componentDidMount() {
    API.get('project')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({ 
          columns: data.response,
          ordered: Object.keys(data.response)
        }, () =>
          console.log("old ", this.state.columns.length)
        )
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Using the debugger built into your browser, put a breakpoint on the `this.setState` line and look at `data.response`. Apparently, it's not what you think it is (since if it were, what you're doing would work).

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... what about it doesn't work?

Comment: @OliverRadini it's "Undefined". I updated my code

Comment: That's strange... I'm curious as to why you get `undefined` logged, and not either `0`, if the array is empty, or `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are destructuring the `response` object from XHR and get directly the `data` field and then, you call again a `.response` on it. This is equivalent to write `responseFromXHR.data.response`. Try something like the following :

These 2 syntaxes are equivalent

```
// old syntax
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
```

VS

```
// destructuring syntax
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .then(function ({data}) {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

I don't know exactly what you API retreives, but something like this seems better :

```
componentDidMount() {
    API.get('project')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        // debugger; // uncomment to display debugger in chrome and check `data` value
        this.setState({ 
          columns: data,
          ordered: Object.keys(data)
        }, () =>
          console.log("old ", this.state.columns.length)
        )
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
  }
```